# SQL Server containment partial

Tags: sql-server, collation, containment

Trying to set partial containment to an existing database

```
ALTER DATABASE [EMS_3518_2] SET CONTAINMENT = PARTIAL WITH NO_WAIT
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Msg 12814, Level 16, State 1, Procedure XXXXX, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   The object referenced as 'dbo.XXX' resolves differently in the target metadata collation 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC' than in the current metadata collation 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS'.

Not sure how to sort out this issue.

Comment: Moving from a case-sensitive collation to a case-insensitive one can cause name or resolution conflicts. Check the proc code at line 10.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks for this! that worked since the table name was uppercase but used in lowercase in the SP...  thanks!!!